# How can i simulate action on generated "alert" or "confirm" from chrome extension to browser page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, alert

I have box message on webpage generated by alert or confirm command. From chrome extension I need to click on "ok" or "cancel" on this box (in web browser). I see this not possible from content script and js level, so I searching in ChromeDevTools protocol, but can't find solution there. How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: No way except for an external utility that can send a keypress. It can be written to support nativeMessaging so your extension would be able to launch/control it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alter the prompt() or confirm() or alert() functions on the original page. You can't do that directly via content script, you need to add a script element on the page.